# linkedin invalid redirect_uri

Tags: facebook, magento, magento-1.9, google-signin, linkedin-api

[image]

invalid redirect_uri error occured in facebook , linkedin ,google+ logins after adding the social login in the magento my website url is http://www.jobixstore.com/

can anyone let me know what to be add in the following

Authorized Redirect URLs:
Default "Accept" Redirect URL:
Default "Cancel" Redirect URL:

Comment: How did you add this, via an extension or …?

Comment: using extension only

Answer (score 0):

It may help to read up on how OAuth 2.0 works with LinkedIn's APIs.  More information can be found here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

In a nutshell, your Magento platform has to have a "listener" endpoint somewhere that LinkedIn will redirect to.  I would hope that if you are using a plugin with Magento of some sort, that it would make it clear to you what the callback value should be.

If you are developing your own OAuth code, you would be free to create whatever endpoint you wanted to receive the token back from LinkedIn, and you would use that value in your application's LI configuration.